# Create Platform specific Views in KMM Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm very new to Kotlin and Compose Multiplatform but I wonder if there is a way to create Platform specific `Views` between iOS and Android.

I've managed to make a Platform specific Button for Android but the one for iOS is not visible. The application does run on both platforms without errors.

Usage in `App.kt` in `commonMain`:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp


@Composable
fun App() {
    var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    MaterialTheme {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            ) {
                Text("Counter: $counter")
                PlatformButton.createButton("Click to increase Counter") {
                    counter++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My expect class in `commonMain`:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

expect class PlatformButton {
    companion object {
        @Composable
        fun createButton(label: String, onClick: () -> Unit): Any
    }
}
```

My actual class in `androidMain`:

```
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

actual class PlatformButton {
    actual companion object {
        @Composable
        actual fun createButton(label: String, onClick: () -> Unit): Any {
            return Button(onClick) {
                Text(label)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My actual class in `iosMain`:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import kotlinx.cinterop.ExperimentalForeignApi
import kotlinx.cinterop.ObjCAction
import platform.UIKit.UIButton
import platform.UIKit.UIButtonTypeSystem
import platform.UIKit.UIControlEventTouchUpInside
import platform.darwin.NSObject
import platform.darwin.sel_registerName

actual class PlatformButton {
    actual companion object {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
        @Composable
        actual fun createButton(label: String, onClick: () -> Unit): Any {
            val uiButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeSystem)
            uiButton.setTitle(label, forState = 0u)

            val block = object : NSObject() {
                @ObjCAction
                fun buttonClicked() {
                    onClick()
                }
            }

            uiButton.addTarget(block, action = sel_registerName("buttonClicked"), forControlEvents = UIControlEventTouchUpInside)

            return uiButton
        }
    }
}
```

I've searched for documentations but couldn't find any. I also don't really like the use of `UIKit` in `Kotlin`. Isn't there maybe another way of using `SwiftUI`-Code and somehow create a `Composable` `View` out of it with a bridge? What I'm also wondering: Is there a specific return type for such a use case instead of `Any`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS, you create `UIButton` and expect compose to draw it, but it doesn't know how to render this view.

To bridge `UIKit` view into Compose, you need [`UIKitView`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/compose-ios-ui-integration.html#use-uikit-inside-compose-multiplatform):

```
UIKitView(factory = {
    val uiButton = ...
    uiButton
})
```

Also, you don't need a class to define expect compose function, you can declare it directly - it'll make your compose code look much more natural:

```
@Composable
expect PlatformButton(...)
```

```
@Composable
actual PlatformButton(...) {
    UIKitView(factory = {
        ...
    })
}
```

Comment: Nice, thx. But do you or anyone else know if there is a way to use SwiftUI for writing iOS specific views and use them in the expect compose function for iOS?
I found this doc: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/compose-ios-ui-integration.html#use-swiftui-inside-compose-multiplatform. The UIKit variant works but the SwiftUI variant is a riddle for me.

Comment: @Gipfeli it's hard for sure - you can use UIKit since it's written in ObjC, and SwiftUI requires Swift, which is not available from KMP. Documentation suggests the only available way so far - creating SwiftUI view in Swift, wrapping it to `UIView` using `UIHostingViewController` and then passing it to kotlin, where then you can wrap it with `UIKitView`. I have no other suggestions other than copying doc code carefully and sorting out how it works. You may be able to have single entry point, where you pass all needed SwiftUI components, that will be used in compose, but it's a challenging task